# Use case diagram can't name my actor properly

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case, use-case-diagram

So I have a problem. I'm making a use-case diagram for an e-commerce store. But I've been told that one of my actors can't be named server as it's not outside of the system. Any Ideas on what this actor can be called instead? This actor is taking care of most admin functions. Below is a simple image of what it looks like.

[image: Here is the picture]

Comment: I suggest you have a look at this question asked very recently for more elaborate explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101348/moving-in-an-actor-inside-system-boundary-of-uml-usecase-diagram/55109587#55109587

Comment: "can't name my actor properly" in a lot of cases when we cannot find the 'right' name for an element that means the element by itself is problematic ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an actor to represent the server. The server is part of your system, and in use case analysis you treat the system as a black-box.

You should simply delete the current Server actor.

Comment: I had it figured thank you for the reply! So instead in this case it's basically just the customer performing an action. What then is recived on the server part is treated as a black-box.